# TexLive Manager - tlmgr version conflict (2013-2014)

Tags: texlive, linux

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. I've just downloaded and installed Tex Live 2014 with the script made by the team behind Tex Live 2014. Now I want to use a package in my IDE (TeXStudio), but I cannot install it through the package manager, because it tells me that my local installation of Tex live is 2013 and the package manager only supports 2014.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: use `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends texstudio`, or (perhaps better) build and install an equivs package, see http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html

Comment: I had a similar problem a few days ago and I think the [hint from tug.org](http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html) is a bit confusing. There is a paragraph about the fake (equivs) package in an answer to [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu) question, which helped me a lot.