# Having a problem with TexLive Manager - tlmgr version conflict 2013

Tags: texlive

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. I am trying to install latex on my computer and decided to use Texlive.  The install seems to have worked properly but when I try to use tlmgr, I get the error:
        (running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
        tlmgr: The TeX Live versions supported by the repository
        http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet
        (2014--2014)
        do not include the version of the local installation
        (2013).

I have never installed the 2013 texlive version and I set my PATH variable so that the command `tex --version` sees that I have Texlive 2014.  I still get the same error.  I know this is very similar to [TexLive Manager - tlmgr version conflict (2013-2014)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199475/texlive-manager-tlmgr-version-conflict-2013-2014) but I tried all the responses to this question and nothing worked.

Comment: If you installed TeX Live using Ubuntu's package manager, you cannot update the system installation using `tlmgr` and `tlmgr`'s functionality is restricted to user-mode. It is possible that you have two versions of TeX Live installed. This is not necessary and tends to cause a lot of confusion so it is better to either use your distro's version or to use upstream's installer - rather than mixing the two. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu if you want to use upstream's version and uninstall TL through Ubuntu's package manager.

Comment: As superuser, you may add the path of your TeXLive 2014 installation (something like `/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux`) at the beginning of the `PATH` variable in the `/etc/environment` file (then restart your session).

Comment: Please [read this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196451/packages-to-install-once-for-all/196466#196466) to a related question, maybe you'll find it useful.